# Collision Filtering with Andengine - How to?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm developing an Andengine-based game and I'm stucked in a collision issue. I have several sprite classes with the respective physic body and I want to ensure that collision only happens with specific bodies. Let's say that I have in my scene bodies A B C and D at the same time but I want to configure collision for only two of them, for example A and C. How do I do that?

Thank you very much for your patience in advance! I'll appriciate any tip!

Comment: Have you tried collision mask bits ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set proper userData for every type of body:

`bodyA.setUserData("bodyA");
bodyC.setUserData("bodyC");`

then you can disable collisision like this:

```
List<Fixture> fixtureList = bodyA.getFixtureList();
for(Fixture fixture : fixtureList){
    if(fixture.getUserData().equals("bodyC")
        fixture.setSensor(true);
}
```

It takes all fixture connected to bodyA and iterate through them. If any of fixture has userData set to "bodyC" it will disable collision detection for it. You can turn it on by setting false instead of true (true means 'disable collision')

Probably it's not the best way to do it but it works.

PS I can't test it now so probably u might have to change someting (add !=null or something) But i think you got the point and you will be able to do it:)

Comment: Hi Mateusz!

Thank you very much for your answar! I understand what you're suggesting! However, i'm trying to implement a collision filter. Check this example: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsCollisionFilteringExample.java
I consider that this is the best way of doing it, in my particular case! But I cannot reproduce the expected results :S

Comment: Everything is about FIXTURE_DEFS of your bodies. In the Fixture def consturctor you can pass one more parameter which is mask of other bodies to collide with. As you can see in the example BOX only colide with other BOX and WALLS etc. 48-64 lines in the example are the most importants where whole magic happens

Comment: Yes, I tried to focus that lines too. However with no success. Bodies are not colliding as it is expected. I know that I'm doing something wrong, but right know, I don't have a clue of what is failling. When I get this working, I'll share ;)

Comment: You can share your not working version here and I will try to help;)